# Why date +3 equals 3?

Tags: command-line, date

Yes, this is a minor issue, but I wonder why

```
date +3
```

outputs

```
3
```

Other options like:

```
date -3
```

raise an error.

Comment: But what were you trying to accomplish anyway?

Comment: Return the n day from today.

Comment: That is done with `date -d"@$(($(date +%s) + $((3 * 24 * 3600))))"`. You did not ask the correct question.

Comment: Well, I asked what I wanted to know: why this way went wrong.

Comment: I wanted to learn how to do it so much :D.

Comment: Oh actually there is no need for the double quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the plus glyph is a format specifier.

In general, in UNIX *programs*, arguments with a minus glyph are options for the *program* and arguments with a plus glyph are *commands* for the *program* (see `man less`).

Manual page `man date` shows more information on this topic.

Comment: +1 *But:* The generalization (options vs. commands) does not apply here, since `date` is never interactive.  Also `+` is NOT a format specifier, it indicates the start of a [parameter string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_(Unix)#Formatting) (this string then *contains* format specifiers, but `+` is not one of them) The relevance of `+` is indicated in the man page synopsis, `date [OPTION]... [+FORMAT]`, "FORMAT" being the format string.  Of course, this still doesn't explain why `date +3` spits out `3`...it should be an error.

Comment: Why not? I like `date +3%s3%Z3`.

Comment: Hmmm, good point.  `date +"**"%s"**"%Z` works too. Kind of un- or very ambiguously documented unless you read the `info coreutils` stuff tho.